# Show that $A$ is open and the complement $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus A$ is infinite

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $(X,d)=(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, L^\infty)$

Let $C=\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}$, and $A:=C^c$.

To show that $A$ and $C$ are infinite, define $f_A\colon \mathbb N\to A$ by  $n\mapsto (n,\frac 12)$, and $f_C\colon \mathbb N\to C$ by $n\mapsto (n,1)$.

I know that $A$ is the set of ordered pairs where the first coordinate is a real number and the second coordinate is a real number that is not an integer.

I'm trying to figure out how to show that $A$ is open and that $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus A$ is infinite

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$ the same set you called $C$ (and showed is infinite) just before?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$ is infinite because $\mathbb{R^2}$ is infinite?

Comment: When you write $C^c$, do you mean $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$ ? In that case you already proved that $C = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ is infinite (the equality follows by De Morgan's Laws). On the other hand $L^\infty$ uses to denote the vector space of almost everywhere bounded functions of some measure space, what metric are you having in mind when you write $L^\infty$?